# Where does this gray solid line come from in plot?

Tags: plotting

[image]

Where does this gray solid line come from?
It's not y=0 or x=0.
Sometimes it occurs, sometime does not.

I can't really produce a smaller example that does the same thing as it is really "random". The full code is a bit long but some dummy code:

```
Plot[f0val^0.5, {f0val, 0, 120}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, Mesh -> 20, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, GridLines -> {{5.3, 114, 22}, {4, 9}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Blue], Directive[Dashed, Blue]},
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 14]
```

This has ALL options that I used to produce the first graph except the data(function used).

I hope it's enough to identify the problem?

[image]

Comment: Try `Axes -> None`

Comment: @wxffles Thanks! I see that someone had voted to `close` this. I might delete it myself if there are more people thinking the same thing.

Comment: @wxffles, your observation is probably worth an answer.  It's not easy to figure out that `Axes` are the problem from the documentation.  Chen Stats Yu, the close vote was because someone thought the code did not reproduce the problem.  If I change the interval to `{f0val, 5, 120}`, I get the gray line on V10.0.2.  (The important thing is not to include zero, I think.)

Comment: I have expanded my comment into an answer.  I agree that it is a good question.  The simple answer is just one of those things you remember with experience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple example of the problem can be generated with:

```
Plot[x^0.5, {x, 30, 120}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: 1]

Here we have a vertical line at 40.  If we plot this without the frame:

```
Plot[x^0.5, {x, 30, 120}, Frame -> False]
```

[image: 2]

We see that this actually corresponds to the axes that Mathematica generates.

```
AxesOrigin /. Options@Plot[x^0.5, {x, 30, 120}]
```

> `{40., 5.4}`

So why would Mathematica make the axes cross there?  If it were the usual `{0,0}` then we'd have a lot of ugly wasted space in our plot:

```
Plot[x^0.5, {x, 30, 120}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: 3]

Instead Mathematica will zoom in on the graph we asked for, but it has to adjust the axes origin to fit them in the same picture.  When we use a frame we often don't want these axes anymore, so `Axes -> None` will get rid of them.

```
Plot[x^0.5, {x, 30, 120}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

[image: 4]